# How to disable transparent background of electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I created a electron app. When the app starts, a login window opens with transparent background. I want that when user logged in successfully. Window's transparent property should be disabled. I didn't find any method like `win.tranparent(false)`. How can I disable the transparent background.

What I tried.

```js
ipcMain.on('load-home-page', () => {
    const win = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()[0];
     
    win.transparent(false);
    win.maximize();
    win.loadURL = path.join(__dirname, '../renderers/pages/index.html');    
    win.show();    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `win.transparent(false)`, which I'm pretty sure doesn't exist, try `win.setOpacity(1)`. It will set your window's opacity to `1` (fully opaque) while `0` will make it fully transparent.

Link to docs: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetopacityopacity-windows-macos

If that doesn't work, perhaps you'll need to destroy your login window and create a new one for the rest of your app's functionality.

Comment: i think there's a difference between set the window to be transparent and set the content with an opacity. One is to leak the color from behind and one is to paint the color